# Intellij can't initialize plugins

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, log4j

**OS:** 64x Windows 7
**IDE:** IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4

After activating the plugins log4j and IdeaSpring, IntelliJ wants to restart itself. While restarting IntelliJ, there are 2 messages which prompt that either log4j and IdeaSpring couldn't be initialized.

How can I set up my IntelliJ that those 2 plugins work?

---

Messages:
Plugin IdeaSpring failed to initialize and will be disabled:
Could not load API connector for IntelliJ IDEA build #IC-129.713
Please restart IntelliJ IDEA.

*and*

Plugin IdeaSpring failed to initialize and will be disabled:
com.intellij.javaee.ExternalResourceManager.addStdResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/langString;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
Please restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IdeaSpring is a third-party plugin which wasn't adapted to the API changes in IDEA 9 (note that it hasn't been updated since 2006) Please report the problem to the plugin vendor (http://www.yanaware.com/)
BTW, Intellij Idea has its own Spring support - why do you need using third-party plugins?

Comment: Probably because he's using the community edition. That one doesn't have support for Spring.

Comment: Yes I have the community edition. I'll take a look at the ultimate edition thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question is: you shouldn't. The plugin you're trying to install IdeaSpring) is from 2006. You should use the Ultimate Version of IntelliJ, which has excellent Spring support. The free version doesn't.

The same for the other plugin; it's also very old, and probably doesn't work anymore. I'm not sure if you need that one, since IntelliJ also has support for most of the XML log4j provides.

I'd say: try the Ultimate version, and either buy it or try to get a free version if you're working on a Open Source project.

Alternatively, if you can't spare the money, you could have a look at [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools), which is pretty decent too, but at least it doesn't cost money, and it does have support for Spring.

Comment: I will take a look at the ultimate version. Thank you for the tips